# UseEfffect: cannot read property

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, mern

I trying to get the data from mongodb and display on a table. I am using useEffect to call the get function. But sometimes an error pops up, it said can't read " details.user._id" , BUT Sometimes, it work it can display the data. Anyone can help? or is there a clean way to do it?  Any tips and helps are much appreciated in advance!

my UseEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getProfile();
    getUser();
}, [getUser(), getProfile()])
```

below is my data that I wanted to get && the getProfile returns this:

[image]

below is rendering a table:

```
  const render_userProfile = (details, index) => {
    return (
        <tr key={index}>
            <td>{details.user._id}</td>
            <td>{details.user.fullName}</td>
            <td>{details.user.email}</td>
            <td>{details.icNumber}</td>
            <td>{details.phoneNumber}</td>
            <td>{details.dob}</td>
            <td>{details.gender}</td>
            <td>{details.address1 + " " + details.address2 + " " + details.city + " " + details.state + " " + details.zip}</td>

            <td>{details.date}</td>

        </tr>
    )
}
```

Comment: your dependency array should not call the functions `[getUser, getProfile]`

Comment: yes sir, I removed it but the error still exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is happening because in intial render when react starts rendering, the `details` state is empty and it has no `_id` property or any property and thus it throws an error. `useEffect` runs after the initial render. so your data comes late. So use conditional redering.

```
const render_userProfile = (details, index) => {
    return (
        <tr key={index}>
          <tr key={index}>
          {
            Object.keys(details).length ? 
            <React.Fragment>
          
              <td>{details.user._id}</td>
              <td>{details.user.fullName}</td>
              <td>{details.user.email}</td>
              <td>{details.icNumber}</td>
              <td>{details.phoneNumber}</td>
              <td>{details.dob}</td>
              <td>{details.gender}</td>
              <td>{details.address1 + " " + details.address2 + " " + details.city + " " + details.state + " " + details.zip}</td>
              <td>{details.date}</td>
            </React.Fragment>
            :
            <td>Loading...</td>
          }
        </tr>
    )
}
```

Here the data will only render if details has some objects in it otherwise it'll render `loading...`